# print text from voice recognition in text view , except the first

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am using simple voice recognition .

I got it successfully working .

Lets say i spoke "Remark hey this is stack overflow"

I want to exclude "Remark" and print the rest of the text in a TextView.

Following is my work onActivityResult :-

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)

        //If Voice recognition is successful then it returns RESULT_OK
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ArrayList<String> textMatchList = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if (!textMatchList.isEmpty()) {
                if(textMatchList.get(0).contains("Field"))
                {
                    Intent non_field = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,NonFieldActivity.class);
                    startActivity(non_field);
                }
                else if(textMatchList.get(0).contains("Tour"))
                {
                    Intent non_field = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,TourPlanActivity.class);
                    startActivity(non_field);
                }
                else {
                    final Dialog list_dialog;
                    ListView voice_match_list;
                    list_dialog = new Dialog(this);
                    list_dialog.setTitle("Matches");
                    list_dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    list_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.voice_list_dialog);
                    voice_match_list = (ListView) list_dialog.findViewById(R.id.voice_list);
                    voice_match_list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            textMatchList));
                    Button cancel_button = (Button) list_dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button_voice);
                    assert cancel_button != null;
                    cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            list_dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    list_dialog.show();
                }

            }
            //Result code for various error.
        }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR){
            showToastMessage("Audio Error");
        }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR){
            showToastMessage("Client Error");
        }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR){
            showToastMessage("Network Error");
        }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH){
            showToastMessage("No Match");
        }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_SERVER_ERROR){
            showToastMessage("Server Error");
        }
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
  /**
   * Helper method to show the toast message
   **/
   void showToastMessage(String message){
      Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

My studies from google:-

`.replace` can be useful here, not able to understand how to use it with my code. Can some one suggest me article or help me with certain logic ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by split method.

```
String message = "Remark hey this is stack overflow";
String [] arr = message.split(" ", 2);
```

Now `arr[0]` will contain `"Remark"` and `arr[1]` will contain `"hey this is stack overflow"`